# Find maxima and minima using Lagrange multipliers

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

Find the minimum distance from origin to the intersection of $xy=6$ with $7x+ 24z=0$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: We want to minimize d=x^2+y^2+z^2 and with two constraints xy=6,7x+24z=0.

Comment: I tried to use two LaGrange multipliers  one for xy=6 and one for 7x+24z=0